# How to tackle "Statement is unreachable [unreachable]" with mypy when setting attribute value in a method?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

#### Problem description

Suppose a following test

```py
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.value: int | None = None

    def set_value(self, value: int | None):
        self.value = value


def test_foo():

    foo = Foo()
    assert foo.value is None
    foo.set_value(1)
    assert isinstance(foo.value, int)
    assert foo.value == 1 # unreachable
```

The test:

- First, checks that `foo.value` is something
- Then, sets the value using a method.
- Then it checks that the `foo.value` has changed.

When running the test with mypy version 1.9.0 (latest at the time of writing), and having [warn_unreachable](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-warn_unreachable) set to True, one gets:

```
(venv) niko@niko-ubuntu-home:~/code/myproj$ python -m mypy tests/test_foo.py 
tests/test_foo.py:16: error: Statement is unreachable  [unreachable]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

#### What I have found

- There is an open issue in the mypy GitHub: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11969 One comment said to use [safe-assert](https://pypi.org/project/safe-assert/), but after rewriting the test as

```py
from safe_assert import safe_assert

def test_foo():

    foo = Foo()
    safe_assert(foo.value is None)
    foo.set_value(1)
    safe_assert(isinstance(foo.value, int))
    assert foo.value == 1
```

the problem persists (safe-assert 0.4.0).  This time, both mypy and  VS Code Pylance think that `foo.set_value(1)` two lines above is not reachable.

### Question

How can I say to mypy that the `foo.value` has changed to `int` and that it should continue checking also everything under the `assert isinstance(foo.value, int)` line?

Comment: How about asking `mypy` to ignore narrowing by first assert? https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=1b7dc7dff3c6ce36a7bb1616afcae8ce

Comment: @STerliakov nice technique! I was wondering if somethiing like this is possible. No other complaints from me than that VS Code Pylance complains that the code in the `if not TYPE_CHECKING` block is not reachable. But it works with mypy and pytest.

Comment: Code in `if not TYPE_CHECKING` block is not reachable for your language server? Go ahead and report a bug, sounds terrible...

Comment: It seems so. Tested on VS Code with the latest release (Pylance language server 2024.3.1 (pyright version 1.1.351, commit 87171fbf)) and latest pre-release (Pylance language server 2024.3.101 (pyright version 1.1.355, commit a2831b73)).

Comment: Hmm. You could [use a TypeGuard function](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=warn-unreachable&gist=92c9f6a03087162d8f8dd47434cc273e) to work around this. I think mypy should know better, but I guess it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly control type narrowing with the [TypeGuard](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec/narrowing.html#typeguard) special form ([PEP 647](https://peps.python.org/pep-0647/)). Although normally you would use `TypeGuard` to farther narrow a type than what has already been inferred, you can use it to 'narrow' to whatever type you choose, even if it is different or broader than the type checker has already inferred.

In this case, we'll write a function `_value_is_set` which is annotated with a return type of `TypeGuard[int]` such that type checkers like `mypy` will infer type of `int` for values 'type guarded' under calls to this function (e.g., an `assert` of `if` expression).

```py
from typing import TypeGuard, Any

# ...

def _value_is_set(value: Any) -> TypeGuard[int]:
    if isinstance(value, int):
        return True
    return False

def test_foo():
    foo = Foo()
    assert foo.value is None
    foo.set_value(1)
    assert _value_is_set(foo.value)
    # the next line is redundant now, but can be kept without issue
    assert isinstnace(foo.value, int) 
    assert foo.value == 1 # now reachable, according to mypy
```

Normally, `mypy` should treat `assert isinstance(...)` or `if isinstance(...)` in a similar way. But for whatever reason, it doesn't in this case. Using `TypeGuard`, we can coarse type checkers into doing the correct thing.

With this change applied, mypy [will not think this code is unreachable](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=warn-unreachable&gist=92c9f6a03087162d8f8dd47434cc273e).

Comment: I think this is a great way to solve the problem! Even more generic solution is to use `_T = TypeVar("_T")` and `def is_instance(val, klass: Type[_T]) -> TypeGuard[_T]: return isinstance(val, klass)` which saves from the trouble of writing multiple helper functions. And one thing to note is that TypeGuard is only available on Python 3.10 onwards, so one might need to use [typing-extensions](https://github.com/python/typing_extensions).

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question and playing around with `safe_assert` I noticed that the v. 0.4.0 [uses](https://github.com/wemake-services/safe-assert/blob/f9bd9f18a7e3b3bd303c7b1bbd9cf1a0ac721c4a/safe_assert/__init__.py#L7) [NoReturn](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/typing.html#typing.NoReturn) as the return type. Removing that makes mypy happy. So in essence, one may use this as `safe_assert`:

```
def safe_assert(
    expression: bool,
    message: Optional[str] = None,
):
    if not expression:
        if message:
            raise AssertionError(message)
        raise AssertionError
```

Comment: Submitted issue: https://github.com/wemake-services/safe-assert/issues/130